# Why do I get two JPEG files instead of RAW+JPEG when transfering to my computer from my Nikon D5100?

Tags: raw, troubleshooting, nikon-d5100, file-transfer, jpeg

I have a Nikon D5100 and I want to shoot RAW and JPG at the same time. I select RAW+N (RAW plus Normal Size JPG). Now when I export the shots to my computer I end up with two files called DSC_0123 (1).jpg  and DSC_0123.jpg. (Both files are the same size). I am missing the raw NEF file. Why is the camera doing this and is something set wrong?

Note: When shooting in RAW only the files are produced normally and function as expected. The firmware is the latest Version (1.01). I have 3 modes for RAW + JPG -- They are RAW+B (Basic) RAW+N (Normal) RAW+F (fine) all three produce JPG and no raw file.

Here are a few ideas that I have tried:

- Reset Camera Settings
- Try another memory card (Note: The memory cards I have are all Transcend 16GB Class 10)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a suggestion. If you are using Nikon's View NX2 (or Capture NX2) then raw+jpeg is a waste of space. The generated jpeg in raw+jpeg is generated by applying in camera setting to raw. View NX2 does exactly that.

Comment: @Lynda If you set to RAW does if produce a NEF file on its own?

Comment: @Vikas - I use Photoshop and Camera RAW to edit my photos. I do not use the Nikon Software.

Comment: @Rob I was gonna ask the same question now

Comment: @Rob - Yes, when shooting just RAW I have NEF Files.

Comment: @AkramMellice - It works normally when shooting in RAW only. I edited question to reflect that piece of information.

Comment: @Lynda What version firmware is the cam - you can find this in the menu?

Comment: @Rob - The latest version (1.01) according to Nikon.

Comment: Can you do this... can you reset the shooting menu (usually the top option on the cam shooting menu)( this will reset all settings) then try just setting raw + jpeg and take a shot - Let me know the results - other test is a diffrent SDHC card maybe?

Comment: @Rob - I will attempt that in a few and post the results here. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Cool - if that fixes it I will post as an answer

Comment: @Rob - Yeah, unfortunately that did not work, I edited my question. Any other ideas?

Comment: That is not expected functionality. RAW+JPEG should be exactly that - you mentioned you select RAW+N - are there any other RAW+JPEG modes eg RAW+F - if so does that work?

Comment: @Rob - I just attempted that and all 3 produce the same results. Edited question to reflect new information.

Comment: Ah ha ! http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1034&message=21930545&changemode=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1034&message=38261447&changemode=1

and

http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1034&message=21930545&changemode=1

You will need to have [Nikon's Transfer software](http://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/61/~/current-versions-of-nikon-software#Anchor-8) or use [View NX 2](http://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/61/~/current-versions-of-nikon-software#Anchor-1)

UPDATE: As a side tip (maybe you already do this) but I **never** connect my DSLR to the PC I always use one of [these](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Integral-USB-Single-Slot-Reader/dp/B000VY80AM/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1335899717&sr=8-1) - Bottom line is - I dont want something to go wrong with my camera on the PC - I would much rather a memory card take that hit.

Comment: Thanks for the help and information. I have been connecting my camera to the PC to transfer files (then I immediately disconnect). I will try a card reader and if I must I will install Nikon's Software.

Comment: What could the computer possibly do to the camera? Everything in the camera is hardwired, surely?

Comment: Not to scare monger - but I know USB carries a current (I have seen short circuits on USB before) that aside - wear and tare on the camera - The interface used is different than when using a SDHC (as a mass storage device) - I would save the connection to the camera for tethering - that way the wear and tare is significantly less - I think this might be more me being pedantic but its one of my habits and im happy with it :)

Comment: Other advantages include you will not put additional drain on the camera batteries and some card readers transfer images to the computer faster than transferring direct from a digital camera

Comment: Thanks again for the information. Using a card reader solved this issue, both the NEF and JPG files show without issue and I did not install any Nikon Software. Also some older Nikon models do allow you to change to "mass storage mode" vs "PTP" mode. Newer models are only PTP hence the problem I was having. The links in your answer cover those in more detail. And I agree with you it is better to play it safe and use a card reader rather than risking any parts of the camera. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem today with the same camera. Actually nothing is wron with the camera or the memory card. I used to downlod on my new DELL laptop with Windows 7 64 bit Professional. Everything was fine.

Today I downloded on a Windows XP machine and found the same problem of yours. I was shocked to see the problem thinking that my camera software was corrupted. It was not. when i went back to may Windows 7 DELL laptop, everything was again fine.Both the NEF & Jpeg files downloaded. So it is the incompatibilty of Windows XP Vs Nikon D5100.

Before that I desperately Google searched the WEB and came across your post.

So the answer is use Windows 7.

Comment: Hi @Sivakumar, welcome to PhotoSE. Your answer sounds insightful, however it would help if you had a reference to back up the claims. Are there newer/alternative versions of the software that might work better with Windows XP? Are there alternative software packages that will work on XP? For that matter, the OP did not specify an operating system, so it might be prudent to verify that the problem they are experiencing is on the same platform.